# Elasticsearch get data where field not null / field is null or field exist / field not exist

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I m using elasticsearch spring data and I want add filter where I can search by field exist/field not exist or where field value is null/not null. How I should do that?

I know Im should use something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "price"
              }
            },
            ...     <-- your other constraints, if any
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Bu how implement it in elasticsearch spring data?

```
Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getUid()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(???????));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may like to use `org.elasticsearch.index.query.FilterBuilders` to build your `exists` filter

```
FilterBuilders.boolFilter().must(FilterBuilders.existsFilter("price"))
```